# Select SQL Server table data using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to select/retrieve all data from SQL Server using ASP.NET.

I've tried this code...

```
SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select * from comment where ID='" + st + "'", con);
SqlDataReader drr;

drr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();

while(drr.Read())
{
    user_name.Text = drr["Username"].ToString();
    date.Text = drr["Date_Created"].ToString();
    userrcomment.Text = drr["Comment"].ToString();
}
```

The code works fine but it can select only one record from database but I want to select all the records...

Also can any one tell me that how to use two/multiple queries using only one data reader....

Any help will be appreciated...

**Update:** problem is when the query run then only the last record will show, but I want that all the record will show against the mentioned id...

**Update 2** this is my page code, as I am new in asp.net, so how can I get the username and other data in span or p tag...

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="140px" Width="378px">
    <p>  
    <asp:Label ID="user_name" runat="server"></asp:Label> Commented on <asp:Label ID="date" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
    <asp:Label ID="userrcomment" runat="server" Height="31px" Width="378px"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: you are passing an id which might retrieve only one record in your select command `("select * from comment where ID='" + st + "'", con);`

Comment: Also only the last values will be shown in textboxes.

Comment: Remove your where clause the you'll get it all

Comment: i have multiple records on the same ID, so logically it will select all the record from database whos Id is like 8, but it will select only one...

Comment: Have you debugged it ? Because only last row values will be shown in textboxes.

Comment: would you have any primary key for this table?

Comment: yes i have two tables, question,comment  in question ID is primary key, and in comment i use the id  like when someone enter the comment on id 2 question then the comment table has id =2...

Comment: So comment table does not have any primary key. Right? Just a foreign key.

Comment: yes, its ID is foregin key

Comment: You need to run a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query to verify that your `Id` has more that one associated records. If this is case, then the only problem can be what @mason state in comments below, "the resulting data is being assigned to a textbox, so the values are getting overwritten".

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting only one records then there are two possibilities.

1. `"select * from comment where ID='" + st + "'"`   In your where condition satisfy for only one record.
2. You are using `SqlDataReader`    in `while` loop if there are many records you got but  you can only see last record bcoz  it will be overwrite last record in every loop.

   ```
      while(drr.Read())
         {

               user_name.Text = drr["Username"].ToString();
               date.Text = drr["Date_Created"].ToString();
               userrcomment.Text = drr["Comment"].ToString();

       }
   ```

   the `user_name.Text` will replaced with last record.

Comment: There's a third possibility. `select * from comment where ID=@id` can return multiple records, as long as ID isn't the primary key for the table. Which is what Shoaib stated in a comment on the question.

Comment: Yeah @mason  but I think first possibility is same if column ID is not a Unique  it may have unique record.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute multiple select queries using a single DataReader. There is an article namely,"Executing multiple SQL statements as one against SQL Server" in CodeProject. Please read it, you will get solution for sure.

```
  using(SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnetion(ConnectionString))
  {
     using(SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select * from comment where    ID='" + st + "'", con))
     {
        using(SqlDataAdapter adapter=new SqlDataAdapter(cmdd))
        {
           DataTable dt=new DataTable();
           adapter.Fill(dt);

           //Bind the datasource with a repeater control in which you can  place textbox control. It will repeat for every data rows.


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is otherwise working, and you want to see all the data in just the three text boxes instead of some more tabular format.

```
SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select * from comment where ID='" + st + "'", con);
SqlDataReader drr;

drr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
while(drr.Read())
{
    user_name.Text += drr["Username"].ToString();
    date.Text += drr["Date_Created"].ToString();
    userrcomment.Text += drr["Comment"].ToString();
}
```

Notice instead of overwriting the value of the textbox, I'm appending strings to it because I used `+=`. You might want to concatenate a `,` to it also.

---

More likely with multiple records though, you want to have them get in a table. The easiest and most straightforward way to do this is:

Code Behind

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from comment where ID=@id");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", st);
var dt = new DataTable();
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Markup

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to place the record into a dataset for you to get all the data you're trying to Retrieve

```
SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select * from comment where ID='" + st + "'", con);
    SqlDataReader drr = new SqlDataReader(cmdd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
                    user_name.Text = dr["Username"].ToString();
                    date.Text = dr["Date_Created"].ToString();
                    userrcomment.Text = dr["Comment"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: That still will show only the last record, because you're overwriting the value of the textboxes for each record.

Comment: @mason actually not, try adding a temporary variable for you to manipulate on each and every data you're iterating during the foreach statement

Comment: It's not my question. But yes, it will only show **the last record**. That's how ASP.NET works. You update the value of a control, and whatever the value was last set to is what gets sent down in the response to the client.

Answer (score -1):

**select/retrieve all data from SQL-Server using ASP.NET**

using this SqlDataReader (sqldr) GetValue for all the records

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringsName"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = "select * from comment where ID='" + st + "'";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataReader sqldr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (sqldr.Read() == true)
    {

        user_name.Text = sqldr.GetValue(2).ToString();
        date.Text = sqldr.GetValue(3).ToString();
        userrcomment.Text = sqldr.GetValue(4).ToString();

    }

    sqldr.Close();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: This will only show the last record, because you're overwriting the value of the textbox for each record.